# change select color when certain option is selected vue

Tags: vue.js

how can I make it so that when a certain option is selected, the select text color changes to red in vue js?

this is my select in which i want the text color to be changed (I need it's value to remain null)

```
<select>
    <option value="null" class="uk-text-danger">.:: test ::.</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Please be more specific.

Comment: @tauzN what is there to specify?

Comment: Give an example of what you would do, and what would then happen. Your code shows one option, why?. Or even better: give some centext, so we can help with a solution to your problem.

Comment: Select tag in HTML is limited in styling options. Some combinations of OS + browser allow more styling, some less. Typically, `<select>` tags are styled by OS and are not style-able via CSS. If you want control over their visual aspect, consider creating your own dropdown using `<div>`s or use any library containing dropdowns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Styling elements like `select` is usually not the right thing to to, instead I would recommend building a custom dropdown and style that instead.
It's easier and far more customizable.

A quick example with Bootstrap's dropdown:

```html
<template>
    <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">
            Dropdown button
        </button>
        <div class="dropdown-menu">
            <a v-for="i in 5" :key="i" class="dropdown-item" :class="{ 'text-danger': selectedOption === i }" href="javascript:void(0);" @click="selectedOption = i">
                Option {{ i }}
            </a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="javascript:void(0);" @click="selectedOption = null">
                Cancel
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script setup>
    const selectedOption = ref(null);
</script>
```

If you need the value to stay null, just don't use any value binding and you are good to go